# Looking for tool/software to create HDR photos on OSX

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, hdr

does anyone know a good tool to create HDR photos on OSX?

Freeware or paid?

From Windows I know:

- Photomatix Pro
- Picturenaut
- FDRTools

any hint?

Answer (score 1):

[Photomatix Pro](http://hdrsoft.com/) is available for [Mac](http://www.hdrsoft.com/download/mac.html).
Overall, it's the best HDR tool I've used. The UI is somewhat complex, but not obtuse. The results are consistently impressive.

Another app that I've seen used (but not used personally) is Nik Software's [HDR Efex Pro](http://www.niksoftware.com/hdrefexpro/usa/entry.php).
This is a powerful app that seems to produce some very nice images.

Both of these are paid apps with free trials.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty experiences with [Hydra Pro](http://www.creaceed.com/hydra/) (paid, but you can get a free trial). Haven't tried anything else though.

Comment: thanks will give it a try - is it a plugin for lightroom though?

Comment: There are plugins for Lightroom and Aperture, yes.